# Django model referring to self throws errors

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have a problem to define Django model where the Primary Key is UUID5 that base on model fields.

Here is what I have got already.

```py
class Place(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid5('PLACE_UUID_NAMESPACE', '{}{}{}'.format(self.city, self.zip, self.country)))
    city = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField(default='US')
```

The problem is with referring to model field as I did `self.city, self.zip, self.country`. Django does not accept the way I did.
How can I define the uuid5 using model fields?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is with referring to model field as I did `self.city`, `self.zip`, `self.country`. Django does not accept the way I did.

Yes and Django is right. **[You do not have an access to `self` yet until you have an instance of the class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)**. So try this instead:

```py
class Place(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    •••
```

[So that if we instantiate an instance with for example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects):

```py
aPlace = Place(city=“Bournemouth”, zip=“blah”)
```

Now we have `aPlace` Which has by default, a random but unique identifier ([UUID](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122.html)) in it’s `uuid` field and a `CountryField(default='US')` in it’s `country` field. Also `city` field is `“Bournemouth”`, and `zip` is `“blah”`. 
[Then you can manipulate the instance right before saving to database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects). That is where you change certain fields for example the `uuid` field.

```py
aPlace.uuid = uuid.uuid5('PLACE_UUID_NAMESPACE', '{}{}{}'.format(aPlace.city, aPlace.zip, aPlace.country))
aPlace.save()
```

Or directly [override the save method of the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods):

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.uuid = uuid.uuid5('PLACE_UUID_NAMESPACE', '{}{}{}'.format(self.city, self.zip, self.country))
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you @Chukwujiobi Canon for detailed explanation and help. What you proposed works in 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's possible, since you don't have access to the instance from the callable default argument.

Your best chance is to set random default uuid and use pre save signal to override it with what you want.